# jQuery - Get id dynamically from generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is get the id name of newly added item in the list on click. Here's my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul>li').on('click', function() {
    var idName = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(idName);
  });

  $('#add').click(function() {
    var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    $('ul').prepend('<li id="name-' + n + '">New Item</li>');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li id="name-88">Old Item</li>
  <li id="name-59">Old Item</li>
  <li id="name-48">Old Item</li>
</ul>
<button id="add">Add Item</button>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xdntu4e/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$(document).on('click', 'ul>li', function(){});` instead of `$('ul>li').on('click', function() { });` this is because you are adding the element dynamically after the jquery code is loaded. Thus, `$('ul>li').on('click', function() { });` will not detect `click` event on the newly added element. To overcome this, you need to assign the click event to `ul>li` at `document` level so whenever a new element is added it is in the context of `document` and listens for the `click` event on `ul>li`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', 'ul>li', function() {  
    var idName = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(idName);
  });

  $('#add').click(function() {
    var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    $('ul').prepend('<li id="name-' + n + '">New Item</li>');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="name-__">New Item</li>
  <li id="name-88">Old Item</li>
  <li id="name-59">Old Item</li>
  <li id="name-48">Old Item</li>
</ul>
<button id="add">Add Item</button>
```

Comment: binding it on `document` might not be the most efficient option. Why not put it on `ul` instead?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings it will not work in that way too because the elements are added dynamically after the DOM has been rendered.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BoyWithSilverWings/4xdntu4e/2/

Answer (score 0):

To get the id of a newly created item, use ele:first CSS property.
call it on click method.

```
let new_el_id = $("ul").find("li:first").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your listener each time new item added, Try

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  addListener();

  function addListener() {
    $('ul li').on('click', function() {
      var idName = $(this).attr('id');
      alert(idName);
    });
  }

  $('#add').click(function() {
    var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    $('ul').prepend('<li id="name-' + n + '">New Item</li>');
    addListener();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  //
  <li id="name-__">New Item</li>
  <li id="name-88">Old Item</li>
  <li id="name-59">Old Item</li>
  <li id="name-48">Old Item</li>
</ul>
<button id="add">Add Item</button>
```

Comment: This is totally not an appropriate way to achieve this. It adds extra overhead.

Comment: Thats right, thanks! :) @AnkitAgarwal

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('ul').on('click','li', function() {  
    var idName = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(idName);
});
```